# Pushing to remote repository after merge "creates new remote heads" - is that bad?

Tags: mercurial, merge, repository, push

1. I `initialized` a Mercurial project on **`Machine A`**, `committed` my changes and `uploaded` them to a remote repository.
2. Then I `cloned` that repository on **`Machine B`**, `committed` some additional changes and `uploaded` them to the same remote repository.

In both cases, I uploaded the changes with the same command:

```
hg push https://username:password@domain/user/repository/
```

Now I'm back on Machine A and I've `pull`ed from the remote repository and `merg`ed any changes between the two changesets using the `KDiff3` GUI tool using the commands:

```
hg pull
hg merge
hg commit
```

However, when I try to push the latest changes from Machine A back to the remote repository after this pull and merge, I get this message:

```
hg push https://username:password@domain/user/repository/
pushing to https://username:password@domain/user/repository/
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote heads!
(did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)
```

**Why does it say "did you forget to merge"? -- I completed the merge.**

**Is it bad to force the push and create "new remote heads"?**

**If so, how do I avoid this?**

---

*UPDATE:*

I ran "`hg merge`" again and got this output:

```
5 files updated, 1 files merged, 0 files removed, 1 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg up --clean' to abandon
```

So I ran '`hg up --clean`' and it reported:

```
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Now when I type '`hg heads`', it says:

```
changeset:   11
tag:         tip
parent:      9
user:        eggdrop
date:        Tue Oct 20 16:27:44 2009 -0400
summary:     Machine A after merge

changeset:   10
parent:      7
user:        chickensoup
date:        Thu Oct 15 03:27:23 2009 -0400
summary:     Machine B changes to be pulled onto Machine A
```

Comment: Yes, I resolved all differences and committed the merge. So, when I type "hg status" there is no output because everything local has been checked in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ran `hg up --clean`. That means you undid the merge, which means you still need to merge. You have an unresolved file when you merge. Re-read your error message:

```
5 files updated, 1 files merged, 0 files removed, 1 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg up --clean' to abandon
```

You need to resolve the merge conflict and then complete the merge with `hg resolve`. Then you will have successfully merged your two heads.

And to answer your question: no, it's not *bad* to have two remote heads. It just means you need to merge them (preferably ASAP) before you push anything else to the remote server.

So to fix, just run `hg merge`, resolve the one conflict, then run `hg resolve`.

Comment: Why do you have to merge them? Where is the problem? I need a change just for one build (patch of old release) and don't want it to merge to normal default...

Answer (score 2):

First: View your changes with `hg log`.
The following didn't help in my case:

- `hg pull` and `hg merge` (before you pull check against hg incoming)
- or: `hg pull --rebase`

But this helped.

```
hg merge [revision]
```

I found that I needed to explicitly merge some revisions which looked like heads.