# Mercurial will not let me push. Abort: push creates new remote head

Tags: mercurial

I can't push using mercurial, it states I have to merge. If I do hg merge, will it merge my branch with the main trunk, I really want to avoid that.

I created and modified some files. I did hg add to add them all. I did some commits but it won't let me push them to my branch.

I posted my output of hg commands below:

```
C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg incoming
comparing with https://stcalica@bitbucket.org/nickrsan/hydroinformatics
searching for changes
no changes found

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg status
M hydro\forms.py
? graph_test.py
? hydro\mlgraph\__init__.py
? hydro\mlgraph\test.py
? hydro\plugins\__init__.py.orig
? hydro\urls.py.orig
? hydro\views.py.orig
? public\Hydroinformatics\media\test.txt
? public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_EPALM1I.txt
? public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_OIWsXcC.txt
? public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_v5s6RmF.txt

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg add
adding graph_test.py
adding hydro\mlgraph\__init__.py
adding hydro\mlgraph\test.py
adding hydro\plugins\__init__.py.orig
adding hydro\urls.py.orig
adding hydro\views.py.orig
adding public\Hydroinformatics\media\test.txt
adding public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_EPALM1I.txt
adding public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_OIWsXcC.txt
adding public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_v5s6RmF.txt

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg push
pushing to https://stcalica@bitbucket.org/nickrsan/hydroinformatics
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote head b54ae56acf07 on branch 'WITHOUTPLUGINSGRAPHS'!
(merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads)

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg commit -m "added files"
abort: last update was interrupted
(use 'hg update' to get a consistent checkout)

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg update
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg branch
WITHOUTPLUGINSGRAPHS

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg status
M hydro\forms.py
A graph_test.py
A hydro\mlgraph\__init__.py
A hydro\mlgraph\test.py
A hydro\plugins\__init__.py.orig
A hydro\urls.py.orig
A hydro\views.py.orig
A public\Hydroinformatics\media\test.txt
A public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_EPALM1I.txt
A public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_OIWsXcC.txt
A public\Hydroinformatics\media\test_v5s6RmF.txt

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>hg summary
parent: 36:b54ae56acf07 tip
 actually added template
branch: WITHOUTPLUGINSGRAPHS
commit: 1 modified, 10 added
update: 10 new changesets, 2 branch heads (merge)

C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing to remote repository after merge "creates new remote heads" - is that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597273/pushing-to-remote-repository-after-merge-creates-new-remote-heads-is-that-ba)

Comment: Btw i am the only one pushing to this branch so i dont expect conflicts from another collaborator

Comment: use thg - and then you will see exactly what the situation is. You prolly committed before you did a pull / update, and have a multi headed branch. If so you prolly just want to rebase your draft changes. (or merge if you don't want to keep your commits linear)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push creates new remote heads! (did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724300/push-creates-new-remote-heads-did-you-forget-to-merge-use-push-f-to-force)

Answer (score 3):

OK, first of all, let's sort out our terminology here.  In Mercurial, a "head" is a changeset with no child changesets (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Head).  Let's say you're working in default branch.  If you're being told that pushing would create new remote heads, it means there's a different head revision in default on the remote repository (the one you're pushing to).  If you pushed, default would have two head revisions!

How does this happen?  Well, it might be another developer did a push in the meantime, or you pushed from another repository/computer by mistake.  You don't want to push a branch with multiple heads, otherwise you end up with some crazy hydra with loads of heads, none of which has all the code.

First you need to pull from the remote repository.  Next, you need to run "hg merge" - if you're using Hg-Workbench or similar, you might not see the other head immediately, so scroll down and find it.  If you have conflicts, now's the time to resolve them.  Make sure you commit your merge, and then you should be able to push.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a verison of Mercurial that's not more than a couple year's old do: `hg push --new-branch` which the `hg help push` shows lets you push a new branch:

```
--new-branch            allow pushing a new branch
```

That'll only be necessary the first time you push a new branch -- it's just there to make sure you don't accidentally push something you didn't mean to share.

Comment: will everything go back to normal, or will I have some weird too headed branch thing going on? lol